# Why does Firefox app connect to Facebook sites very often according to TrackerControl?

Tags: privacy, firefox-for-android

I noticed for a while using the app TrackerControl that Firefox connects to Facebook sites very often while I surf the web, for example a simple search on Google, or a search on Startpage.com which sites don't have anything in their pages linked to facebook sites.

I have set TC to block trackers in Firefox by default.

#### Trying to find out when this occurs

I thinked that this happens in general until now. In fact before writing this question I did some tests and I noticed **one probable behaviour causing** connections every time, that is if I search a string through a Firefox's search engine in search bar. This happens both with predefined engine (google) and with custom one (startpage). This tests was done when I've just opened Firefox in private browsing so that there wasn't other working tabs (and there was no loaded facebook tabs opened in normal browsing tabs).

Here is TrackerControl after a Startpage search (from bar) where Facebook domains result blocked 5 seconds ago:
[image: TC after google search]
Here after a Google search (from bar) where Facebook's domains result also blocked 5 seconds ago:
[image: TC after startpage search]*Note:*  <del>probably (as I remember) instagram's domains are there because I visited it once and it wasn't blocked yet. The relevants domains here maybe are:
*scontent-fco2-1.xx.fbcdn.net* ,
*scontent.xx.fbcdn.net* and
*static.xx.fbcdn.net*</del>
 The domains contacted are probably all that appear in the screen under Facebook (see 2<sup>nd</sup> update).

But I noticed just sometimes that connections happen also if I only interact with firefox's bar and digit something.  Than if I just use a page like this and I don't touch search bar, connections to facebook seems to not occurs since TC indicates that some minutes passed after the last connection. But now after about 30 minutes another connection was made even if I didn't touch search bar.

#### Who is the actor

This behaviour is strange and it seems probably is acted by Firefox itself, but it should not. I've never heard or read that Firefox communicates  with Facebook and there is no reason, but only with Google for scanning URLs and downloads. Also after searching there are no results.
I don't have strange extensions. Moreover I have the ext. *μBlock* and *Noscript* that should block facebook together because I explicitly set the first to block Meta's websites in general and the second to block other non website's scripts by default. So those connections in TC should have never occured I suppose except if they are made by Firefox, at which level every extension can't operate. Read 1<sup>st</sup> update.

The problem occured for months, but I postponed this question until now. This means that I noticed this also with older versions of Firefox before the present since more or less one year ago.

**Note**: TrackerControl app says explicitly that it doesn't support blocking trackers in browsers yet, but I understood I could use it anyway.

#### My complete "configuration":

- Firefox from Play Store, version *114.2.0* (for successive versions see bottom)

  - Extensions: *uBlock Origin*, *NoScript*, *Decentraleyes*, *Google search fixer*, and other non relevant here but installed noramally from Firefox
  - I have search suggestions disabled so no contact should there be while texting in bar. Moreover I have studies disabled and just "technical data and usage" enabled.
- TrackerControl app installed from F-Droid, version *2023.01.31-fdroid*
- Android version 8.0.0 (I don't think is relevant)

I'm not an expert of TrackerControl. I hope that someone know what is the reason because is not a good thing.
Does Firefox do this in its code or is just an error of TrackerControl (I don't think)? If it's a tracker seems too invasive. Has someone experienced this or can reproduce this?
Thanks in advance.

---

#### Updates:

- As asked in comments, disabling all extensions and restarting Firefox (also rebooting Android) doesn't eliminate the problem, connection persists after a search on the bar.
- I tried app NoRoot Firewall in place of TC (both are VPN based); it gived connections to facebook (and also to instagram) in log right after a search. But Firefox connections was all allowed in rules of NoRoot Firewall. After I re-enabled TC (disabled NoRoot F.), which blocked facebook, those connections was more sporadic or absent for some time. But after one day of use (always with TC block activated) the problem returned as before, so the browser tries to connect at least after every search in bar.
- I want to note that those facebook domains which I look often are marked "Essential" by TC. There are some other Facebook domains under "Social networks" which seems also to be tried to connect to after a search.
- All this happens on that Firefox I have installed; if I install a new one all this things don't happen like other users reported.

#### Versions:

I've checked if connections to facebook continue in newer versions and I noticed that them happened after every search in these ones: 115.2.1, 116.0.0(this not sure if typed correct), 116.2.0, 116.3.0, 117.0.0, 117.1.0, 118.1.2, 119.1.1, 120.1.0 (current)
Just in version 118.1.1 I noticed very rare connections also after days, but they occurred.

Comment: Based on the package name visible in your screenshot you don't use Mozilla Firefox, but instead use Mozilla Fenix.

Comment: @Robert TC before showed just Firefox, but then this because I've not waited refreshing the list, in fact now shows me Firefox again. The application is Firefox. I've installed from play store the normal version. As I know Fenix is the new codename for Firefox from few years, when its code was renewed. Before was Fennec. Another application shows me the name *org.mozilla.firefox*.

Comment: Could be an error from tracker control (I never used that). I opened a search of Firefox and checked [adguard](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-android/overview.html) logs and I don't see what you mentioned in your question

Comment: Just in case, have you tried disabling all extensions and tried it again?

Comment: @AndrewT. I've just tried disabling all ext.,  closing and restarting Firefox. After searching on startpage, I go to trackercontrol and again "Facebook 4 seconds ago".

Comment: @beeshyams basing on your comment I tried disabling TrackerControl and activating NoRoot Firewall (a VPN based firewall) and tried some searches from browser bar. I had everything allowed for Firefox so I looked on the log and found another facebook related link (also instagram) right after search. Than I reactivated just TC and the searching from bar didn't trigger facebook's connections like before but they was rare or absent. After a day of use of Firefox while TC was activated, situation returned like before.

Comment: I've checked tabs in normal browsing one by one closing some eventual facebook related site (but those tabs which are inactive should not work in background maybe). But even after this the problem remains.

Comment: @bonzo With any update, you may want to update which versions of software you did testing on. I would be curious to know if [Firefox Focus](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=firefox+focus&c=apps) has a similar issue as your testing configuration as it is aimed at being a more privacy based browser.

Comment: Please try testing on a fresh installation of Fennix or Firefox with no browser tabs open.  Then open a single tab for https://www.example.com - This will be a much more useful and conclusive test.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Hi I'll add that, I taked note. I've tested (at least checked) in all this versions and in all there was those connections;  versions 115.2.1, 116.0, 116.2.0, 116.3.0, 117.0.0, 117.1.0, 118.1.2, 119.1.1
120.1.0 (current) connected at every search, just 118.1.1 connected to facebook a few times during days. I don't know why. After that version, returned the same. I tested a little Firefox Focus, thanks for suggestion, and TrackerControl shows no connections to facebook, just some Firefox related and google (content-autofill).

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate If I can have the possibility I'll do it.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate I've tried on another smartphone a new Firefox and with Tracker Control I saw there was no more connections to Facebook at all. Every search from bar even after days were as they should be. Also adding custom engines. This makes me think that something(fb?) inserted that behaviour in the Firefox app, after his installation, like a spyware integrated that persists with updates. Maybe Firefox could change something that will make this things impossible, I suppose.